# How can i remove .html from static html website pages

Tags: html, url, url-rewriting, web, permalinks

I have a static website with static files (pages), I would like the URLs of the pages not to contain .html at the end, for example: 
"www.mywebsite.com/page.html" to become "www.mywebsite.com/page"
of course I can't just redirect the page, since the file "www.mywebsite.com/page" isn't known
Thanks in davance

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). This question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use URL rewriting for your server's config file. 
For example if you are using an apache server, you could use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html[NC,L]
```

in your .htaccess file (which is the config file for your apache server.